# Unrecognized selector sent to an instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, parameter-passing

I have three methods which are taking parameters,

I am taking exception at this parameter giving,

```
[QuestionnaireView continueSingle:withQuestion:question:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a4b1c0
```

What am i doing wrong? Its definition is also given in the header file.

Here is my code;

```
-(void) continueSingle:(id)sender withQuestion:(Question*)quest{

int counter = 0;

NSString * tempAnswer;

for(UIView* subview in [sender superview].subviews)
{

    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if([((UIButton*)subview) isSelected])
        {
            counter++;

            tempAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",((UIButton*)subview).currentTitle];
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here

```
-(void) continueSingle:(id)sender withQuestion:(Question*)quest
```

Because you are passing three parameter but you're receiving only two parameter. So you need to take 3 parameter. Like this..

```
-(void) continueSingle:(id)sender withQuestion:(Question*)quest question:(Question *)question1
```

Comment: i am passing as this; @selector(continueSingle:withQuestion:question:)

Comment: yes thats the problem. If you wanna only two parameter then you need to pass only two parameter like that @selector(continueSingle:withQuestion:)